# Trivial questions about topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm taking a topology class, and I get wonder about something which seems trivial.

Firstly, sometimes my book or professor denote topological space as:

X or sometimes (X, $\tau$)

What is difference between them?

Also, what is topology of the usual space $R $ ?

I know the basis of the usual space $R$ is (a,b) : interval of $R$ , then what is topology of the space??

Can I choose any interval which satisfies the axiom of topology?

p.s) It seems like $\Tau$ doesn't work.... right?

Comment: \Tau doesn't work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111544/what-is-the-capital-greek-letter-for-tau

Answer (score 2):

strictly speaking a topological space is a pair consisting of a set $X$ and a set $\tau\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ of "open subsets of $X$" (of course satisfying some properties). Thus the correct way to adress a top. space is to write down a pair $(X,\tau)$. However, as people are lazy, they just write $X$ or $\tau$ whenever they feel that the remaining part is clearly given from the context. This is in fact not particular to top. spaces but also other mathematical constructs... someone might for example write $\mathbb{R}^3$ to mean the vector space $(\mathbb{R}^3,+,\cdot)$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual vector addition and scalar multiplication.

As for your second question: 
the usual topology ("the $\tau$") of $\mathbb{R}$ consists of all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ where $Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open iff for every $x\in Y$ an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\{z\mid |z-x|<\varepsilon \}\subseteq Y$ exists. Since every open set can be optained as the union of open intervals (and because open intervalls are open) one says that the topology is generated by the set of open intervalls i.e. the open intervalls constitute a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, a topological space is a pair $(X, \tau)$ consisting of a set $X$ and a topology $\tau$. If the topology is obvious from context, though, we will often omit the $\tau$. For the same reason, we will often talk about "the group $\mathbb{Z}$" rather than "the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$".

The usual (Euclidean) topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has basis $\{(a,b): a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$, as you say. A member of this topology is anything you can obtain by unions and finite intersections. These sets can look very strange; they are precisely those sets $U$ with the property that for every $x \in U$ there is an open ball of some radius around $x$, lying wholly in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is simply the set with no topology on it. $(X, T)$ is the set $X$, along with the topology $T$ enforced on it.

This is important because one set can have multiple topologies on it. For example, let us take $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$. The two most "extreme" topologies one can enforce on this set are:

1. Discrete topology - every subset of $X$ is open. That is, $T = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$

All in all, all "open intervals" will precisely become the open sets of the topology, by taking $B$ as a basis.

2. Indescrete topology - Only open subsets are those dictated by the topology axioms - the empty set and $X$ itself. $T = \{\emptyset, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$

The two topologies give the underlying sets different properties. For example, every function whose *domain* is the discrete topology is continuous. In contrast, every set whose *image* is the indiscrete topology is continuous. Stuff like that.

Since you know the basis on $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all open intervals $(a, b) \ \ a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, the way to **generate** a toplogy $T$ from a basis $B$ is to take arbitrary unions of elements of $B$ and finite intersections of elements $B$.This gives us the topology of $X$ from the basis $B$.

So, the topology $T$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the given basis will have open sets such as:

1. $(1, 2)$
2. $(1, 2) \cup (3, 4)$
3. $(1, 2) \cup (3, 4) \cup \ldots \cup (n, n +1)$
4. $(1, 5) \cap (1, 6)$

etc.

Remember, it will always contain *finite* intersections and *infinite* unions.